# Dismissing camera view crashes app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

When I try to dismiss my UIImagePickerController, it crashes the app. the error is: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'"

I have the preferred interface orientation set in my view controller.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}
```

Here is the method I'm calling to bring up the camera, this works fine for adding the camera, but like I said, crashes when I try to remove the camera.

```
-(IBAction)addCamera:(id)sender
{

self.cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

self.cameraController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.cameraController.cameraViewTransform,
                                                                   1.13f,
                                                                   1.13f);

self.cameraController.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.cameraController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

ar_overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

self.view = ar_overlayView;
[self.cameraController setCameraOverlayView:ar_overlayView];
[self presentViewController:cameraController animated:NO completion:nil];
[ar_overlayView setFrame:self.cameraController.view.bounds];
}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
[ar_overlayView removeFromSuperview];
[cameraController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Also crashes if I try to use the view controller to dismiss the camera, as in.


    -(IBAction)back:(id)sender
    {
    [ar_overlayView removeFromSuperview];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }

Comment: One additional question: where and how is `ar_overlayView` declared?

Comment: It was declared just after my @implementation, not sure what that is called but looks like this.

(at)interface ARViewController ()

(at)end

(at)implementation ARViewController
UIView *ar_overlayView;
UIView *button_overlayView;

(at)synthesize .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found the solution, it was really simple, I just changed my back method to:

```
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now my camera goes away and I can see my original view when I press the back button.
I still haven't figured out what was causing the original problem as I've gone through the info.plist and the methods for supported orientations, but this accomplishes what I wanted.

I'm still curious as to what was causing the error though if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: If all you support is portrait, then `shouldAutorotate` should return `NO`.

Comment: I've tried setting them all to no, and that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try remove this method:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

It will fix it.but sometimes it will lead to reduce stateBar height.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a UIViewController's main view from its superview.

Instead of this:

```
self.view = ar_overlayView;
```

Try this:

```
[self.view addSubview:ar_overlayView];
```

Then you will be able to remove it from the superview correctly.

Comment: Thanks, still crashing though.

Comment: [cameraController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; -- That is the line of code that is crashing my program, if I comment that out, it won't crash.

Comment: Try `[self.cameraController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` instead of `[cameraController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

Comment: Appname[67374:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x381d43e7 0x37060963 0x381d4307 0x376c58b9 0x375a3c37 0x3761446b 0x375607a1 0xde1e7 0x375a2047 0x375a1ffb 0x375a1fd5 0x375a188b 0x375a1513 0x374ca4fb 0x374b78b1 0x374b71bf 0x354555f7 0x35455227 0x381a93e7 0x381a938b 0x381a820f 0x3811b23d 0x3811b0c9 0x3545433b 0x3750b291 0xed047 0xd9b10)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the didFinishPickingMedieWithInfo method similar to below and use [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

    NSLog(@"Camera");


}

else {


    NSLog(@"Album");

 }

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: The app still crashes. Maybe should I move the image picker controller to it's own view controller file and and then call it with the app delegate instead of trying to run it from within the main view controller?

Comment: @StevenMarlowe shouldn't really matter does the app crash when you dismiss the camera without the camera overlay? I have a feeling this is issue maybe...

Comment: And did you add uinavigationcontroller delegate method in your .h? like this @interface TakePicViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

Comment: Added the delegate, I was missing that. Thanks, but it didn't fix the problem. I tried commenting out the code to remove the overlay, so it was still there when dismissing, but that didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add `ar_overlayView` to the current view yourself if it's a camera overlay.

Here's what your code is doing now:

1. Add `ar_overlayView` to the current view
2. Add `ar_overlayView` as the camera's overlay view
3. Show the camera view (modal)

At this point, `ar_overlayView` is being displayed **twice**. When you send it the `removeFromSuperview` message on dismissing the camera view, it might be getting confused since it's in two view hierarchies at the same time.

Skipping the `self.view = ar_overlayView;` or `[self.view addSubview:ar_overlayView];` lines should fix the problem.

Also, `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` should be sent to the same object that `presentViewController:animated:completion` was called on (`self` in this case):

```
-(IBAction)addCamera:(id)sender
{
  // -- snip -- //
  ar_overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.cameraController.view.bounds];
  [self.cameraController setCameraOverlayView:ar_overlayView];
  [self presentViewController:self.cameraController animated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Still not working, I think the answers lies somewhere in the main view controller, but not sure what to do, since I already set the methods for preferred orientation.